# How to hide IPX error message in nuxt3 project with nuxt/image

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

In my nuxt3 project with nuxt/image

When i go to for example:

```
http://my.site/_ipx/f_webp,s_140x85/img/Something/wrong_path.jpg
```

I will 404 status code and IPX error massage:

> IPX Error: Error: File not found
> (**/my/very/secret/path/**.output/public/img/Something/wrong_path.jpg)

I can't redirect this page with tools nuxt3 or vue.

What can I do to hide this information from potential attackers?